# Sorting comments by votes doesn't return 0 score comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, sort, comments

I have a query:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/16822/comments?sort=votes

This doesn't return comments with no votes, setting **min** to **0** doesn't work. [This query](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/16822/comments?sort=creation) includes them all, but isn't sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

That's a bug.

a naked query should return all comments, you should not have to specify min=0 (which is basically a no-op).